# Disk utility in ubuntu desktop

Tags: partitioning

How can I go to Disk Utility in order to rename the HDD partitions? I am trying Ubuntu 12.04 from USB.  Disk Utility is shown as installed but I can't access it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type **Disks** on Dash and then open it.

[image]

Comment: Or you can use gparted to set label for a partition.